# livecode - using mergPop with fullscreenmode?

Tags: livecode

Anyone using mergPop with fullscreenmode?

With this: set the fullscreenmode of me to `letterbox`
the popover does not locate properly. When I try adding the rect of the button it seems to have no effect. Testing in simulator with iPad simulation.

MergPop works great without setting fullscreenmode but I need fullscreenmode.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no API in the externals SDK yet that allows the translation of LiveCode points to UIKit points if you use a fullscreenmode so it's not possible for externals to support these modes properly yet. If you can work out exactly how much of a letterbox you have with the given aspect ratio then you may be able to calculate an appropriate rect for the optional from rect parameter.